# Continuity of $x\log(x^2)$ when $x\neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am going over some undergraduate real analysis and came across a problem in which I am having issues proving that the function $f(x)=x\log(x^2)$ is continuous for $x \neq 0$ using an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof. Here is the work that I have so far:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, choose $\delta>0$ s.t. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ where $|x-c|<\delta$, then $$|x\log(x^2)-c\log(c^2)|=|x\log(x^2)-x\
\log(c^2)+x\log(c^2)-c\log(c^2)|\leq |x\log(\frac{x^2}{c^2})|+|(x-c)\log(c^2)|$$
I believe that by picking $\delta_1=\frac{\epsilon}{2\log(c^2)}$, I can bound the second term by $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ but I am having issues bounding the first term. If this were $\log(x)$ instead of  $\log(x^2)$ I believe I would be able to bound it, but the squared term is messing me up. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*HINT*

I don't know if it helps,  but  you can do this:

$$|x \log{x^2}-c \log{c^2}|=|x \log{x^2}+c\log{x^2}-c\log{x^2}-c \log{c^2}|$$ $$\leq |x-c||\log{|x|^2}|+|c||\log{\frac{|x|^2}{|c|^2}}|$$ $$=2|x-c||\log{|x|}|+2|c||\log{\frac{|x|}{|c|}}|$$

Note that $\log{a^2}=2\log{a}$ for $a>0$

Comment: That log manipulation will only work for a > 0, which is not a restriction that is being considered for this problem. Will update the post to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: @RealAnalysisGrad thats why i put absolute values in the log function,,i forgot to put in one absolute value though,so i edited..I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Consider that $$|x-c| < \delta \quad \iff \quad 1-\frac{\delta}{c} < \frac{x}{c} < 1 + \frac{\delta}{c}$$

So for $\delta$ small enough $\frac{x^2}{c^2}$ is close to $1$ hence $\log\frac{x^2}{c^2}$ is close to $0$.